# Poker ICM Calculator is Incorrect in Python

Tags: python, poker

Hi I'm trying to build a Poker ICM calculator that determines expected value for each player based on stack sizes and the payout structure. It works for when I plug in 3 players at the table, but as soon as I try 4 it spits out incorrect values and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why. Here is my code:

```
# starting vars
players_remaining = [ "p1", "p2", "p3" ]
players_remaining_stacks = [ 4500, 2700, 1800 ] 

# first place pays $84, second $36
payouts = [ 84, 36, 0 ]

# calculate total chips among all players
total_chips = 0
for stack in players_remaining_stacks:
    total_chips += stack

# STEP 1:    
# create a list of all possible finish positions, each possibility has
# the remaining players finishing in a different order
possible_finish_positions = list(itertools.permutations(players_remaining, len(players_remaining)))

# STEP 2: 
# Build matching list of possible_finish_probabilities
# to match possible_finish_positions, probability for each
# position in each scenario
possible_finish_probabilities = []

# loop through every permutation
for finish_positions in possible_finish_positions:

    # % chance of each player finishing where they finish in this permutation
    # this will get tacked onto possible_finish_probabilities when finished
    perm_probabilities = []

    # total amount of chips we've deducted for this permutation
    perm_chips_deducted = 0

    # loop through each finish position
    for x in range(len(finish_positions)):

        player_name = finish_positions[x]
        index = players_remaining.index(player_name)
        player_stack = players_remaining_stacks[index]

        # the odds of this player finishing in this position is
        # their chips divided by remaining chips
        probability = player_stack / ( total_chips - perm_chips_deducted )

        # add to the probabilities for this permutation
        perm_probabilities.append(probability)

        # deduct this player's chips from remaining chips
        perm_chips_deducted += player_stack

    possible_finish_probabilities.append(perm_probabilities)

# now we have two matching lists, 
# possible_finish_positions and a matching possible_finish_probabilities

# STEP 3:
# we can now create the probabilities of finishing in each position for
# each player by looping through all of the scenarios for each player
finish_probabilities = []

# loop through each player
for player_name in players_remaining:

    # initialize probability as 0 for this player
    # finishing in each position
    this_p_probabilities = []
    for x in range(len(players_remaining)):
        this_p_probabilities.append(0)

    # loop through scenarios
    for x in range(len(possible_finish_positions)):

        # this permutation is one possible scenario
        permutation = possible_finish_positions[x]

        # determine where the player finishes in this scenario
        position = permutation.index(player_name)

        # initialize the probability as the probability
        # for the player who finished first in this scenario
        probability = possible_finish_probabilities[x][0]

        # now if this player is not the player who finished first,
        # need to adjust the probability by mutliplying it by
        # the probability for every player in the scenario ahead of this
        # player
        if position != 0:

            print("position not 0, adjusting")

            # loop through everyone in front of this player
            # in the scenario
            for y in range(0, position):

                # adjust the probability
                probability *= possible_finish_probabilities[x][y + 1]

        # if player is 1st in this scenario, their probability
        # is set to this probability of finishing first.
        # otherwise we add it to any other probabilities of the
        # player finishing in this position
        if position == 0:
            this_p_probabilities[position] = probability
        else:
            this_p_probabilities[position] += probability

    # finished probability for this player
    finish_probabilities.append( this_p_probabilities )


print("finish_probabilities=")
for x in range(len(finish_probabilities)):
    print(str(finish_probabilities[x]))


# now I can calculate the EV of each player
# multiply the probability of each position times the 
# payout for that position
player_EVs = []
for x in range(len(finish_probabilities)):

    # get the probability of player finishing
    # in each position
    probabilities = finish_probabilities[x]
    EV = 0

    # multiply probability of each position by the payout
    # for that position
    for y in range(len(probabilities)):
        EV += probabilities[y] * payouts[y]

    # store
    player_EVs.append( EV )

print("player_EVs")
print(str(player_EVs))
```

What's driving me crazy is this code generates correct ICM EV values for these 3 players according to the ICM calculator at https://www.icmpoker.com/icmcalculator/#RXui. However if i change the 3 variables at the top to:

```
players_remaining = [ "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4" ]
players_remaining_stacks = [ 4500, 2700, 1800, 1000 ] 
payouts = [ 84, 36, 0, 0 ]
```

This adds a 4th player to the scenario, and here the EV values are way off. In particular, when I output finish_probabilities near the end of the code, the probabilities for each player look correct for their probability of finishing first, but the other 3 are off and probabilities of each position add up to more than 1 for each player.

I've combed through this code line by line and as far as I know it's doing what I think its supposed to do. I don't get why its correct for 3 players but when I add a 4th it doesnt work.
Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who reviewed this. I believe I found the issue and I'll leave this posted as I don't see any other Poker ICM questions.

The issue is that I was double computing probabilities in some situations. For example, with 4 players, there's 24 permutations of the orders that player's can finish and 2 of those examples are

```
p1, p2, p3, p4
p1, p2, p4, p3
```

In terms of p2 finishing second, I was adding together the probability of both of these scenarios (as well as any other permutation where p2 finishes second) to determine total
probability of p2 finishing second. However this is actually p1 finishing first and p2 finishing second twice, so only 1 of these should be included in the calculation when computing p2's probability of placing second.

I inserted code to ensure while computing p2's probability of placing second (or any other player where players before them in the scenario are identical to some other scenario), to only include 1 of those "identical" scenarios.

Code is working now for any players. Thanks